# Restrictions in creating a plugin

Tags: qt, qt4, qtplugin

Recently tried the plugin example of Qt.
It didn't work at all and I was confused as to the reason. Then found the solution on one of the forums.

*Qt, Application and plugin all three have to be built with the same configuration (Release/Debug)*

This works for me as I can build all three in Debug/Release mode. But if I want users to extend my application using plugins I need to provide debug build of my application. (If I provide release build, users will not be able to trouble-shoot the plugin). Qt source is available so it can be built in any mode.

I don't want to provide debug build of my application to users. Is there any work around for this restriction on build mode for plugins?

P.S. I understand users can debug with logging statements, but not sure how many prefer that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Qt has a so called `build key` which is just a string containing some Qt configuration information, this is documented in the [`Qt plugin Howto`](http://pepper.troll.no/s60prereleases/doc/plugins-howto.html#the-build-key).

So you should just go ahead and provide a debug build of your application for the best results.

Answer (score 0):

You can build debug version (to have compiled in debug configuration) and strip it out of all symbols etc.